# Steps to create certain bit masks?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I'm looking for a general way to create a bit mask using shifts and bitwise operators and to be wary of overflow from shifting left

ex. 0x80000000 would be something like (~0 >> 31) << 31, correct me if I'm wrong

More specifically 0xAAAAAAAA and 0x55555555 is what I'm struggling with

Comment: First off, you don't need to worry about overflow when using unsigned integers. Second, this sort of shifting is only practical for contiguous set bits.

Comment: Assuming a 32-bit (or greater) system, 0x80000000 == (1 << 31).

Comment: @EOF I'm working with signed though!

Comment: @Crowning: There is this magical contruct: `(unsigned)whateverintvariable`.

Comment: @EOF Ah thank you! I didn't know that. However, I'm not allowed to use that in my assignment and I'm kind of curious how to go about masking this alternate way

Comment: @hexturtle that's how I originally did it, but I modified it so it could work in an environment where shifting left 1 << 31 is considered undefined to the C Standard

Comment: @Crowning: You basically *have to* cast. Right-shifting a negative signed integer is implementation-defined, and left-shifting it is **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("0x%08x\n",  (~0 << 31));
unsigned int x;
x = (~0 << 31);
x >>= 31;
x |= x << 2;
x |= x << 4;
x |= x << 8;
x |= x << 16;
printf("0x%08X\n",  x);
x = (~0 << 31);
x >>= 30;
x |= x << 2;
x |= x << 4;
x |= x << 8;
x |= x << 16;
printf("0x%08X\n",  x);
```

http://ideone.com/N3Yx8Z

result

```
0x80000000
0x55555555
0xAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: `x = (~0 << 31);
x >>= 31;` can be replaced by `x=1;` and `x = (~0 << 31);
x >>= 30;` can be replaced by `x=2;`